# jqGrid: configure creatable but not editable values using forms

Tags: jqgrid

I need to allow the user to specify a value on creation but once created I need to disallow editing of that value.

code: 123 value: abc

User can enter both values on creation. But only 'value' is editable.

Using jqGrid and forms to do this.

Using this configuration:

`{name:'code',index:'code', width:50,editable:true,editoptions:{maxlength:"20", readonly: 'readonly'},formoptions:{label:'Code'}, editrules:{required:true}},
                              {name:'value',index:'value', width:100,editable:true, editoptions:{maxlength:"400"},formoptions:{label:'Value'}, editrules:{required:true}},`

But this is not allowing me to create the 'code' entry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't get any answers I used

`$("#code").attr('readonly', false);`

$("#code").attr('readonly', true);

at appropriate locations, and that did it.

I also removed readonly: 'readonly' from editoptions above.